# Continuum many reals with pairwise irrational difference

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, real-numbers

In "Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory" by Péter Komjáth and Vilmos Totik, in the Solutions to Chapter 30, they claim: "It is easy to give continuum many reals with pairwise irrational difference". However, I'm having a hard time constructing such a set. I've tried using an identification of $[0, 1]$ with $2^\omega$ and then constructing a subset of $2^\omega$ such that taking the bitwise difference results in a sequence that does not eventually repeat, meaning that the real number it corresponds to is not rational. However, I can't translate the bitwise difference operation on $2^\omega$ to the subtraction operation on $[0, 1]$.

Edit: I should note that in this chapter, the axiom of choice is explicitly not assumed

Comment: A Hamel basis of the reals [i.e. a basis for the reals considered as a vector space over the field of rationals] has continuum number of elements and pairwise distances [between distinct elements] irrational.

Comment: @coffeemath While true, the appeal to choice is unnecessary and in my opinion obscures a more intuitive argument; see my answer.

Comment: @coffeemath The axiom of choice is not assumed here. I edited the question to include this condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The axiom of choice can be invoked here (e.g. to build a Vitali set) but it is in fact overkill: there is a totally explicit and choice-free way to do this.

The following lemma is easy to prove (here "interval" means "closed and bounded interval with distinct endpoints"):

> Let $\mathcal{K}$ be a finite set of disjoint intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $r\in\mathbb{R}$. Then there is a set $\mathcal{J}$ of disjoint intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ such that
>
> - each $K\in\mathcal{K}$ contains a pair of distinct intervals $J^K_0,J^K_1\in\mathcal{J}$ as proper subintervals (and this is all of $\mathcal{J}$ in the sense that $\mathcal{J}=\{J^K_i: K\in\mathcal{K}, i\in\{0,1\}\}$), and
> - whenever $A,B$ are (possibly equal) elements of $\mathcal{J}$, we have $$\beta-\alpha\not=r$$ for every pair of distinct elements $\alpha\in A$ and $\beta\in B$.

Now iterate this lemma to build a sequence of finite sets of intervals $(\mathcal{K}_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, beginning with $\mathcal{K}_0=\{[0,1]\}$ (say) and continuing by letting $\mathcal{K}_{i+1}$ be built from $\mathcal{K}_i$ via the lemma with $r$ the $i$th rational in some fixed enumeration. This builds us a "tree of intervals" - basically, a function $F$ from the full binary tree to the set of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ - and to form our desired set of reals we just pick for each infinite binary sequence $f$ a real in $\bigcap_{\sigma\prec f}F(\sigma)$, using the finite intersection property of closed-and-bounded intervals.

NOTE: there was a small error in the first version of this answer, now corrected. However, the lemma as originally stated *is* enough if we tweak its application and use, not an enumeration of the rationals, but an enumeration *with infinite repetition* of the rationals - that is, a sequence $(q_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for each rational $p$ there are infinitely many $i$ with $q_i=p$.

*(It's a fun further exercise to show that in fact each $\bigcap_{\sigma\prec f}F(\sigma)$ is a singleton, so the final "we just pick" is actually superfluous.)*

Comment: You didn't mention it, but I believe you have actually shown how to construct a Cantor set of real numbers with irrational differences. More generally, I seem to recall a theorem (Mycielski? Blass?) to the effect that, for any Borel set $B\subseteq\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$, there is a nonempty perfect set $P\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $\{(x,y)\in P\times P:x\lt y\}$ is either contained in $B$ or disjoint from $B$. Or something like that.

Comment: I don't think the Lemma is sufficient. For example, beginning with the interval $[0, 1]$ and choosing $r_1 = 1/4$, we could obtain $[0, 1/3]$, $[2/3, 0]$. Then choosing $r_2 > 1$, we could obtain $[0, 1/9]$, $[2/9, 1/3]$, $[2/3, 7/9]$, $[8/9, 1]$. Now, these 4 sets of course satisfy the condition for $r_2$, but they don't satisfy the condition for $r_1$ anymore, since we have $1/24 \in [0, 1/3]$, $7/24 \in [2/9, 1/3]$ and $7/24 - 1/24 = 1/4$. So while the Lemma does always guarantee the condition for the current $r_i$, it makes no statement about the condition for all the previous $r_i$.

Comment: @Smiley1000: Agreed that’s a problem as written, but it’s easily fixed: in the lemma’s condition “$\alpha - \beta \neq r$ for all distinct $A, B \in \mathcal{J}$ and $\alpha \in A$, $\beta \in B$”, the word *distinct* should be removed.  Then the lemma is no harder to prove (you just need to cut down the new intervals to length $<r$), and now the condition is preserved when we subdivide further.

Comment: Proving the lemma seems easy if we only care about the overlap between $K$ and $K+r$ for each individual interval $K$, but simultaneously handling all the potential overlaps between different intervals in $\mathcal K$ seems more fiddly. I wonder if I'm missing an easier approach.

Comment: @Smiley1000 Good catch, and there are actually a couple ways to fix this; see my edit!

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Indeed, fixed now.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Why did you remove the part about letting the intervals always become half as small so as to ensure that the intersections only contain a single point?